# How to prevent computer from going to sleep

Tags: windows-7

On Win7SP1 I have a long job to run and want to save monitor power. I turn off the monitor. A few moments later the Win7 PC goes to sleep (cutting the job). I don't want that.

I want the Win7 PC to continue working on the job with the monitor off. What's the relevant control?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into your computer's sleep/power settings. On Windows 10, you can access these settings by going to `Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Power Options`.
I am assuming this should be the same for Windows 7 or you can search for power settings but you should be looking in control panel of your version of Windows.